# CSS ::first-letter selector breaks line spacing

Tags: css

When making the first letter bigger than the rest of the paragraph (like in the story-telling books) the spacing of first line breaks:

```
p::first-letter {
    font-size: 250%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7zka3jsy/

As you can see the first line has bigger space than the rest of the paragraph, because the :first-letter doesn't move just up, but also down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by setting the proper **[`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)** and **[`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)** for the first letter as so:

```
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 250%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  line-height: .9em;
}
```

**[Fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/nm897yst/2/)**

**Or,** simply apply some tidy ***[dropcase](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/drop-caps-historical-use-and-current-best-practices/)*** book-like styling as so:

```
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 250%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

**[Fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/nm897yst/1/)**

Comment: The key here is using `em` units for line-height nice solution ++

Comment: `Line-height` does not work with `:first-letter` and `float` on Firefox (64.0.2) :-(

Comment: Current version is 66.0.1, better upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

```
p::first-letter {
   font-size: 250%;
   line-height:.9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `line-height: 18px;` to `p` tag

```css
p::first-letter {
font-size: 250%;
}
p{
line-height:18px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pellentesque egestas gravida. In turpis tellus, blandit vel facilisis a, viverra vitae lectus. In vitae ullamcorper nulla, hendrerit condimentum tellus. Morbi purus sapien, convallis et facilisis non, ornare non ante. Morbi et sapien et ante tincidunt lobortis nec a dolor. Nunc id rutrum velit, quis tempor tortor. Suspendisse nec orci non tellus tempus feugiat et quis turpis. Etiam viverra lacus rhoncus dolor vestibulum, in dictum diam ultricies. Praesent urna nulla, finibus ut nulla at, scelerisque posuere nisi. Etiam faucibus turpis sit amet ipsum efficitur vestibulum. Phasellus sit amet ipsum vitae quam euismod ullamcorper. Fusce pellentesque tellus nisl, aliquet luctus est dignissim id. Sed sit amet erat non purus feugiat pretium sit amet sit amet dui. Aenean ligula mi, tincidunt tincidunt dui ac, auctor consequat ante. Proin vitae tincidunt tellus, quis mollis elit. 
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the position to the initial letter using the pseudo class **first-letter** and then add any of the box-model styles such as padding or margin to the html element.

Here is the updated

`Updated JS Fiddle:`https://jsfiddle.net/7zka3jsy/4/

Answer (score 0):

As it's the first letter, and will never go over to two lines, simply set the `line-height` value to `0` in the `p::first-letter` pseudo class selector.

**Example**

```css
p::first-letter {
    font-size: 250%;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

This will allow you to change the `font-size` value in the `p::first-letter` pseudo class selector and/or the `font-size` and `line-height` values(s) in the `p` selector independently.

Setting the `line-height` value to `0` guarantees consistent results across different browser rendering engines, whereas setting its value to some other value (e.g. `0.9`) doesn't necessarily.

Revised [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zka3jsy/5/)